# Why do my scatter plots look exactly the same even though I'm transforming the predictor?

Tags: r, regression

This is the data set that I am using: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine+Quality

I'm using R to make two scatter plots:

```
> plot(chlorides~(1/alcohol),data=redwinedata)
> plot(chlorides~alcohol,data=redwinedata)
```

but the two plots look exactly the same (axes, points, everything). Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I am upvote this question since i was confused back in time. @MichealChernick had the answer !

Answer (score 9):

The plot of $x$ vs $y$ should not look identical to the plot of $1/x$ vs. $y$. I think you made a code error. The code you provided does not transform the predictor.

You need to calculate the variable separately and pass it to plot or use the `I` function. See below for an example.

```
x = runif(100)
y = runif(100)
plot(y ~ x)
plot(y ~ (1/x)) # looks exactly the same. It's a plot of y vs. x.....
plot(y ~ I(1/x)) # does not look exactly the same
z = 1/x
plot(y ~ z) # looks just like the last call but not like the plot of y vs. x
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are misinterpreting the OP's question.

Comment: The OP seemed to be, plainly, asking why the scatterplot looks identical when he/she believes it shouldn't. The answer is that there was a coding error. I don't see what I could have misunderstood.

Comment: You didn't misunderstand at all (it's a good answer). R's formula interface leads to some surprising behavior for new users because formula expressions are processed by (changed by) the formula interface first before being passed to the thing that evaluates "algebraic" expressions, and the formula interface doesn't do what people might anticipate.

Answer (score 1):

You think you're transforming the predictor ... but you aren't.

Here's a small reproducible example using a built in dataset:

```
plot(dist~speed,cars)
plot(dist~1/speed,cars)
```

The problem is that the thing that handles formulas (which you invoked by having `~` in your first argument) passes the formula expression through the thing that processes formulas before the result is passed to the thing that evaluates arithmetic expressions, and often the resulting behavior is surprising to newer users. Some expressions are left alone by the formula interface and others are modified by it.

As GoF_logistic suggests, here's what you should be doing:

```
plot(dist~I(1/speed),cars)
```

(or computing the transformed variable then plotting it), but you can also do this:

```
with(cars,plot(1/speed,dist))
```

either way, you're trying to avoid the formula interface processing the "1/x" type expression. Using `I()` insulates your expression while it passes through the formula interface unchanged; using the `plot(x,y ...)` form of plot function skips the formula interface altogether.

You also need to avoid something like this -  `plot(dist~(speed^2))` for the same reason.

[While the formula interface makes a lot of sense for ANOVA, I'd like to see it modified for plots so that it more often did something less surprising to newcomers (it's presently more often annoying than helpful even for an experienced user). Is there really any need for `plot(y~x^2)` or `plot(y~1/x)` to do anything other than what they seem to ask for on their face?]

Answer (score -2):

It is because of the scale changes on both axes.

Comment: Please don't call this a poor answer just because it is short.

Comment: I know! that is why I upvoted ! OP: please carefully check the plot axis labbels

Comment: It's a poor answer because it's incorrect. For one thing, transforming the x-axis doesn't change the scale of both axes... More to the point, though, this answer implies that the two plots **should** look the same. No, they shouldn't.

Comment: @GoF_Logistic You misunderstood me.  It is not that transforming the x-axis changes the scale of both axes.  What I am saying is that when you transform both axes the scatter plot will look the same.

Comment: Nothing in the title, text or R syntax in the question implies changing the scale of both axes. At most the syntax can be (mis)read as changing the scale of the x axis. It is easy enough to experiment with R to verify this. (As a very occasional R user, I was naively surprised at what it does here, but that's a different and trivial issue.)

Comment: @MichaelChernick, I don't know if that's true. If it's a linear transformation then sure. But plotting $1/y$ vs. $1/x$ does not produce the same plot as $x$ vs. $y$.

Comment: Try generating x and y as random $\chi^2$ with small df and compare plotting them raw and then reciprocal. For me it looks completely different.

Comment: The *only* possible way the two plots could look the same is (1) for each (alcohol, chloride) data point there is a corresponding (1/alcohol, chloride) data point (which seems extremely unlikely) and (2) the x-axis is not labeled.